# Using HTML5 drag and drop, is there a way to get the page title of a dropped URL?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

Currently I am able to Drag from the address bar of a browser, and Drop into another browser window. I am only able to read the URL of the dropped item so far. Does a dropped url item contain a page title? (You will see the title as it is dragged, so I wonder if it contains that.) Or is there a way to reference the first window in JavaScript so as to get the title? (ie. mywindow.title)

Comment: a url contains nothing except what it contains (how meta...). a page title might be encoded within it as a query parameter or an anchor, but there's nothing 'standard' about that.

Comment: You can of course load the page and get the title...